# Setup SSL in Apache on Centos6

Tags: linux, apache, https, ssl-certificate, centos6

I've read many blogs\posts how to do it but still having problems...

I've created a self-signed key+cert files (Common-name= www.mywebsite.com)

I bought a virtual host at *Prometeous*.
I bought a domain name from *Goddady*, and forward the domain name to the ip-address using **https** protocol.

In the web-server I installed mod_ssl and configured ssl.cnf as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/srv/www/mywebsite.com/public_html/"
ServerName www.mywebsite.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl-cert/my_cert_file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl-cert/my_key_file.key
```

**My Problem:** I can't go to the my browser and do: https://my_web_ip_address and it would work!, but if I do https://mywebsite.com than it doesn't work!

**My questions are:**

1. Do I need to edit\add something to the '/etc/hosts' file?
2. What have I done wrong? are forgotten to do?

I appreciate any help I can get with it...

Thank you :-)

Answer (score -1):

You have not included **SSLEngine on** on your VirtualHost,

Follow the below steps to Configure the SSL in Apache.

To Configure SSL in Apache you need to install two packages i.e. :

1. mod_ssl
2. openssl

After Installation required Packages you have to create Self Signed Certificated as described below :

1. Generate Private Key using below Command :

**openssl genrsa -out elinuxbook.key 2048**   # Where "elinuxbook" is the name of the Certificate, You can put any name you want.

2. Generate CSR i.e. Certificate Signing Request :

**openssl req -new -key elinuxbook.key -out elinuxbook.csr**

3. Generate Self-Signed Certificate :

**openssl x509 -req -days 1095 -in elinuxbook.csr -signkey ca.key -out elinuxbook.crt**

After generate the Self-Signed Certificate you have to copy the Certificates to appropriate Path.

Then Enable the SSL Engine in Virtual Host and Set the Path of the Certificates in that.

The VirtualHost would Look like shown below after Configuration.

[Click on the Link below to check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43ygp.png)

Now Just restart the Apache Service and you are Done.